# How to get file path from inside .jar source code

Tags: java, jar

I try to open file.txt with editor.exe

editor.exe is converted from editor.jar that is written on Java

Do I have the ability to get file.txt absolute file path from inside java source code of editor.exe?

[image]

Comment: Is file.txt an embedded resource or external file? Is file.txt associated with the editor, so that when you double click it, it will open the editor or are you trying to access the file internally (such as File|Open for example)?

Comment: File.getCanonicalPath() will get absolute path to a file. However, this all depends on whatever you use to cross-compile your Java code and whether it uses the correct native method to get the file path.

Comment: file.txt is not internal resource, it's some random file on disk. I open it with "Open with..." option and than choose editor.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `main` method; specifically,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // args[0] should be the path that was requested, in which case you
    // could use
    if (args.length > 0) {
        java.io.File f = new java.io.File(args[0]);
        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
            try {
                System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```